# Indicate the need to provide one's email address for having one's avatar

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, gravatar

It took me several days to understand why my avatar does not display.

It's when I provided my email address in my profile that my avatar automatically appears.

It seems to me it is not indicated anywhere, and I'm not normally a Gravatar user.

Maybe indicate this information under "Change picture".

Comment: The tooltip on the "Change picture" link reads "your gravatar is associated with your email address", but that's maybe a bit weak.

Comment: I actually missed this.